# Validate url and convert into protocol format

Tags: php, url

I am using `file_get_content($url)` which does not work with url starting from `www`.

So I am trying to append the `http://` and converting into proper form if user entered url is not in correct form.

[Check DEMO HERE](http://codepad.org/WardREXm)

```
<?php

$url= 'www.google.com';
$pad = 'http://';
$cmp = 'www';
$prefix = substr($url , 0,2);
if($cmp == $prefix)
{
     echo str_pad($url, strlen($url)+3 ,"$pad",STR_PAD_LEFT);
}

?>
```

This code does not echo correct url. Any issue here?

Comment: Since when is "www" only two characters long?

Comment: Yeah, I'm a newb, right. But I know that the third argument to `substr` is the *length* of the desired string, not the *end offset*!

Comment: Nope, it takes *2* chars *starting at `0`!* If you require proof to believe it: http://3v4l.org/mTsL8

Comment: Gotta love it when 600-repper calls a 168,000-repper a newbie.  Good luck with that, @Karimkhan.

Comment: @deceze and james: I apologize! You are right deceze. I highly appreciate and thank for your efforts.

Comment: None of you down voted my question. That reflects clarity and neutrality of your mind. honor for both of you : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all you need:

```
if (strpos($url, '://') === false) 
    $url = 'http://' . $url;
```

Answer (score 4):

Why not use [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to figure it out?

```
$url = "www.example.com/test.php";
$parsedUrl = parse_url($url);

if(!array_key_exists('scheme', $parsedUrl)){
    $url = "http://" . $url;
}

echo $url;
```

[codepad example.](http://codepad.org/aGKZQMvD)

Comment: thanks but how can I validate it whether it starting from 'www' or it is corretly entered

Comment: @Karimkhan A domain does not necessarily require "www". "www.google.com" is not any more *valid* than "google.com". In fact, some domains are not set up with a www subdomain, adding one would break the URL.

Answer (score 1):

check this

```
$url= 'www.google.com';
$pad = 'http://';
$cmp = 'www';
$prefix = substr($url , 0,3);
if($cmp == $prefix)
{
   echo str_pad($url, strlen($url)+7 ,"$pad",STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
```