# Converting incorrect url to correct url

Tags: php, url

Im am looking for a function that can convert *domain.com* into *http://domain.com/*.

Should I do this with a regex or is there a default php function which can handle this?

I have a bunch of website addresses saved mysql like this:

- domain.com
- www.domain.com
- http://domain.com

I like to convert all of those to http://domain.com. And I am looking for a way to do this good so I won't screw up the website address.

Comment: Please supply some more information. What is the function supposed to do and where? Give us an example.

Comment: So basically it could be `nothing`+ domain, `http://`+domain, `https://`+domain, `http://www.`+ domain, `https://`+ domain?

Comment: @Michel yes just like you wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it like this:

```
$url = 'domain.com';
if (strpos($url, '://') === false) 
    $url = 'http://' . $url;

echo $url;
```

based on: [Validate url and convert into protocol format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20214617/validate-url-and-convert-into-protocol-format?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
$string = "http://www.domain.com";

url_fix($string);

function url_fix($str)
{
  $str = str_replace(array("http://", "https://"), "", $str);
  // string = www.domain.com

  $str = substr_replace('www.', 0,4);
  //string = domain.com

  $str = "http://".$str;
  //string = http://domain.com

  return $str;
}
```

Instead of checking for both `http://` and `www.` and doing a fancy regex for it, you could strip it of both tags (if it has it) and then just prepend `http://` before the final `example.com`.

Comment: I would suggest doing `substr_replace('www.',0,4)` for the www., otherwise you could screw up `bowww.com`